# Failed to build pyarrow during installation of Snowflake-SQLAlchemy through pip installation

Tags: python, pip, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use `Snowflake` `Python` Connector through `SQLAlchemy`, While I am running `pip install --upgrade snowflake-sqlalchemy` I am getting error failed to build pyarrow during installation. I am using `python version 3.7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend reinstalling pyarrow, and then you might want to upgrade snowflake-sqlalchemy after that.  Probably couldn't hurt to redo the standard connector as well, steps as follows:

1.
pip install --upgrade pyarrow

2. pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python

3.
pip install --upgrade snowflake-sqlalchemy

Comment: Thank you very much, I make it work by downgrading python version to 3.6 as pyarrow doesn't support latest version, Please let me know if any workaround to resolve it with Python 3.7.

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you, though I can get to pyarrow at 3.7.4, not sure why you can't.   
$ python3
Python 3.7.4 (default, Sep  7 2019, 18:27:02) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyarrow
>>> pyarrow.__version__
'0.15.0'

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response, I will workaround with your comment and get back to you :) Actually my pip install always pointing (try to install )pyarrow version 0.10.0 and I am not sure how to get latest pyarrrow version.

Comment: did you try ?
   pip install pyarrow==0.15.0
?

Comment: since it is working with python 3.6, I doesn't bother to make any changes in current working environment. but your comments will help me or somebody in future :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped, feel free to "accept" my answer if you don't mind, you can do so by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.